# The formula for the area of two triangles determined by the diagonals of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

I have a trapezoid - a quadrilateral with exactly one pair of parallel. Its bases are $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$, and $\big\vert \overline{AB} \big\vert = 35$ and $\big\vert \overline{CD} \big\vert = 14$; $\big\vert \overline{AD} \big\vert = 17$ and $\big\vert \overline{BC} \big\vert = 10$. According to the formula for the height of a trapezoid, the height of this trapezoid is 8. The diagonals intersect at $P$, and they divide the trapezoid into four disjoint triangle (or four triangles, any two of which share either a side or $P$). I understand that the areas of $\triangle\mathit{APD}$ and $\triangle\mathit{BPC}$ are equal.  What is the area?

A formula at "http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html" states that the area of such triangles in a trapezoid with bases of lengths $a$ and $b$ and height $h$ is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{ab}{2(a + b)} \, h .
\end{equation*}
How is this formula derived?

Here is the code to get a display of the given trapezoid.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}


%A trapezoid ABCD is to be drawn with bases of lengths 35 and 14 and legs of lengths 10 and
%17.  The formula for the height h of a trapezoid with bases of lengths a > b and legs of
%lengths c and d is
%\begin{equation*}
    %\frac{1}{2(a - b)} \sqrt{(-a + b + c + d)(a - b + c + d)(a - b - c + d)(a - b + c - d)} .
    %\end{equation*}
%So, the height of this trapezoid is 8.  (The diagram is magnified by a factor of 1/4.)
%
%The longer base AB is drawn.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8.75,0);
%A line segment that is parallel to AB and 8 centimeters above AB is drawn. The other base
%CD will be part of this line segment.
\coordinate (C') at (3,2);
\coordinate (D') at (7,2);
\path[name path=line_segment_containing_CD] (C') -- (D');
%
%An arc of a circle centered at B of radius 17/4 centimeters is drawn to locate C.
\path[name path=arc_of_circle_to_locate_C] ({(35-10)/4},0) arc (180:150:{17/4});
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_segment_containing_CD and arc_of_circle_to_locate_C, by=C}];
%
%An arc of a circle centered at A of radius 17/4 centimeters is drawn to locate D.
\path[name path=arc_of_circle_to_locate_D] ({17/4},0) arc (0:30:{17/4});
\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_segment_containing_CD and arc_of_circle_to_locate_D, by=D}];
%
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;


%The labels for  the vertices of the trapezoid are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at (0,-0.15){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +(0,0.15)$){$D$};


%The lengths for the bases are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!0.15cm!90:(A)$)$){$35$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(C)!0.15cm!-90:(D)$)!0.5!($(D)!0.15cm!90:(C)$)$){$14$};

%The lengths for the legs are typeset.  (The midpoint of AD is called E, and the midpoint
%of BC is called F.)
\coordinate (E) at ($(A)!0.5!(D)$);
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(D)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(E)!0.15cm!-90:(A)$) +({\n1+90}:0.15)$){$17$};
%
\coordinate (F) at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$);
\draw let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(F)!0.15cm!90:(B)$) +({\n1+90}:0.15)$){$10$};


%A vertical line is drawn to the right of the trapezoid indicating its height.
\draw[|<->|] (9.5,0) -- (9.5,2);
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(9.5,1)!0.15cm!90:(9.5,0)$){$8$};


%The diagonals are drawn, and the intersection of them is labeled P.  (There is a bit more space
%between the label "P" and the point is represents than between the labels for the vertices and
%the vertices.)
\draw[name path=diagonal_AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=diagonal_BD] (B) -- (D);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=diagonal_AC and diagonal_BD, by=P}];
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(0,-0.2)$){$P$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in


\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought it could have a link with the harmonic mean. See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/HarmonicMean.shtml Unfortunately, they don't give a proof. The reference to sangaku is interesting. Did you know these votive figures ?

Comment: @JeanMarie   I haven't seen any of these propositions.  (I vaguely remember, maybe, reading the scenario of two ladders leaning against different buildings.  This is relevant to the 1877 Sangaku in the web site you suggested. I had never heard of the word "sangaku."  These are Japanese wooden tablets on which geometric problems were ornately carved between the 17th and 19 centuries and were hung in temples.) Right now, I am particularly interested in some geometric properties of the trapezoid.  I am sure that I will get back to this web site later.  It would be nice if it gave some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle CPD$ are similar.
Proof: because $AB \parallel CD$ we know that $\angle BAP=\angle DCP$, and $\angle ABP=\angle CDP$, and are similar.

2) area APD=area BCP
Proof: see the triangles $ADC$ and $BCD$, that have the same base $DC$ and the same height (is this case 8). we find that have the same area. Now, both triangles has the triangle DPC inside, and the difference of areas must be equal.

Now, if the height is $8$, we know that $h_{ABP}+h_{DCP}=8$ and $\frac{ h_{ABP}}{h_{DCP}}=\frac{35}{14}$ and we can obtain both heights. Then, we can calculate both areas, and we can find the sum of areas ADP and BPC, because are equal, we finish.

Comment: Very nice.  I see that this argument gives the formulas for the two triangles of equal area.

Comment: Do you know the argument for the formula for giving the intersection of the diagonals, or do you know a textbook in plane geometry that would have it?  Should I make another post?  (I will delete this comment.)